# Reticulate sees some (but not all) python packages using Rstudio on Ubuntu

Tags: python, r, rstudio, conda, reticulate

Setting a conda environment (in this case named `r420v1` where python is in "/home/tjm/anaconda3/envs/r420v1/bin/python3" ) in reticulate "works" in that it sets the appropriate version of python, libpython, and python home.  However, it identifies only numpy (correct version 1.24.2 also seen in `r420v1`), also in the  as the sole package available, but there are dozens more.

```
> use_python("/home/tjm/anaconda3/envs/r420v1/bin/python3")
> # use_condaenv("r420v1")
> library(reticulate)
> py_config()
python:         /home/tjm/anaconda3/envs/r420v1/bin/python3
libpython:      /home/tjm/anaconda3/envs/r420v1/lib/libpython3.11.so
pythonhome:     /home/tjm/anaconda3/envs/r420v1:/home/tjm/anaconda3/envs/r420v1
version:        3.11.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 31 2023, 17:51:05) [GCC 11.3.0]
numpy:          /home/tjm/anaconda3/envs/r420v1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.24.2

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

Moreover, the other python packages I need, `gseapy`, `matplotlib`, and `pandas` are all installed in conda environment `r420v1` but cannot be found.  However, they're there when I run `py_list_packages()` (see bottom row for `gseapy`):
[image]

When my script it fails at the python block where I import `gseapy`:

```
> library(reticulate)
> use_condaenv("r405v1", required=TRUE)
Warning: Previous request to `use_python("/home/tjm/anaconda3/envs/r420v1/bin/python3", required = TRUE)` will be ignored. It is superseded by request to `use_python("/home/tjm/anaconda3/envs/r405v1/bin/python")
> reticulate::repl_python()
 >>> import numpy as np
    >>> np.__version__
    '1.24.2'
>>> import gseapy as gp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gseapy'
```

Previously, when I ran a simplified version of my script in the Rstudio console, only focusing on reticulate, I g0t a completely different error:

```
> library(reticulate)
> use_condaenv("r405v1", required=TRUE)
Warning: Previous request to `use_python("/home/tjm/anaconda3/envs/r420v1/bin/python3", required = TRUE)` will be ignored. It is superseded by request to `use_python("/home/tjm/anaconda3/envs/r405v1/bin/python")
> reticulate::repl_python()
>>> import gseapy as gp
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/tjm/anaconda3/envs/r420v1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I'm using:

- R 4.2.2
- reticulate 1.28
- RStudio "Elsbeth Geranium" Release (7d165dcf, 2022-12-03) for Ubuntu Bionic,
- Ubuntu 20.04.2 "Focal Fossa"

Comment: What does `py_list_packages()` return? What command specifically are you running when you get the ModileNotFoundError?

Comment: It depends, as you'll see by the edits.  The simplified behavior in the console is still throwing an error at importing gseapy, but it's different than when it's run in script.